# Get movies of all genres

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a movie application with ReactJS and the TMDb API, I would like to get the movies by genres, and display them in my homepage, for that I created for example a method `initHorrorMovies()` who:

- Performs an axios TDMb API request for movies of a kind
  https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie-discover
- Changes the state `horrorMoviesList` with new data

The problem is that there are many genres, so I'm going to create as many functions and states as there are genres.

I was thinking of creating a `movieList` object that would contain the results of the tmdb query for each genre as well as the title of the genre, and then update a `movieList` state with that object.

Do you have any suggestions for me?

I tried this

```
 class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
       super(props);

       this.state = {
          movieListWithGenre:[],
       }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
       this.initGenreMovie();
     }

     initGenreMovie(){
       axios.get(LINK_GENRES).then(function(response){
            this.initListMovie(response.data.genres)
       }.bind(this));
     }

     initListMovie(GenreList){
        this.setState({ moviesList: this.state.moviesList.push(newMovies)});

        GenreList.map((element) => {

     axios.get(`${API_END_POINT}discover/movielanguage=en   
        &with_genres=${element.id}
        &include_adult=false&append_to_response=images
        &${API_KEY}`).then(function(response){
            this.setState({movieListWithGenre:this.state.movieListWithGenre.
            push(response.data.results)})
         }.bind(this));
      }) 
    }
  }
```

**Edit**

Hello, I allow myself to go back the post because I develop a solution that works, I am able to get the list of films sorted by genres using the TMDB API request.

My solution works but I have a lot of latency when launching the application because I think the procedure is heavy, performance is impaired.

Here is my code, could I have some tips to improve this code? I thank you in advance for answers.

```
class App extends Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

       this.state = {
           defaultgenre:28,
           movieListWithGenre:[],
           genreList:[],
           genreId:[],
           genreTitle:[]
         }
       }

       componentDidMount() {
           this.initGenreMovie();
        }

        initGenreMovie(){
            axios.get(`${LINK_GENRES}`).then(function(response){
                 this.initListMoviesWithGenre(response.data.genres)
            }.bind(this));
        }

        initListMoviesWithGenre(genres){
            genres.map((genre) => {
               axios.get(`${API_END_POINT}${POPULAR_MOVIES_URL}&${API_KEY}`)
               .then(function(response){
                  let movies = response.data.results.slice(0,14);
                  let titleGenre = genre.name;
                  let idGenre = genre.id;

                  this.setState({movieListWithGenre:[...this.state.movieListWithGenre, movies]});
                  this.setState({genreTitle:[...this.state.genreTitle, titleGenre]});
                  this.setState({genreId:[...this.state.genreId, idGenre ]});

               }.bind(this));
            })
          }

          render(){

             const renderVideoListGenre = () => {
                 if(this.state.movieListWithGenre) {
                    return this.state.movieListWithGenre.map((element,index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="list-video">
                            <Caroussel 
                                key={element.name} 
                                idGenre {this.state.genreId[index]} 
                                movieList={element} 
                                titleList={this.state.genreTitle[index]}
                             />
                        </div>
                      )
                  })
               }
            }

           return (
             <div>
                {renderVideoListGenre()}
             </div>
           )
    }

    export default App
```

Comment: Please provide the code that you try now.

Comment: I updated my post with the code I added

Answer (score 1):

Once you discovered all the genre ids you want you can begin making axios calls to

`https://api.themoviedb.org/<GENRE_ID>/genre/movie/list?api_key=<API_KEY>&language=en-US`

You can make a single function for all genres or split them up, but should likely be called in the constructor. Once your axios calls return, you can put the movies data into your state like so:

```
this.setState({ moviesList: this.state.moviesList.push(newMovies) });
```

The shape of your movie and moviesList object is up to you and the data returned by the API.

Comment: I have already discovered all the id with the tmdb request, but I manage a state for its, it is the thing that had to do or I must use the answer of the request axios?

Comment: Not quite sure i understand. If you know the GENRE_ID's already, then you can begin making axios requests for the movies

Comment: For the push to work, the state movies must be intialised, when I put it to null, I get the error message 'push is not a functions'

Comment: moviesList should be an empty array instead of null, so in the constructor put `this.state = { moviesList: [] };`

Comment: I always have the same error, I updated my post with a code that I add.